# caffeine cache - Limit size to x MB

Tags: caffeine-cache

Is it possible to set caffeine cache size limited to x MB ?

If this is not possible, is there any performance reason for not doing it [For my understanding].

I checked with weighter,  . As per my understanding weight is calculated based on number of time key was accessed. If i understand weight wrongly please guide me with right link

My use case is to set cache size to x-MB and evict once we reach x-MB

Reference  i used:

https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine/maximumWeight

weight based eviction : https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine

Thanks

Jk

Comment: The weight is the units of capacity of an entry, and has nothing to do with its access frequency. If you can calculate a byte size then that is your weight. That can be tricky to do in practice ([JEP-8249196](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8249196)) so Caffeine does not provide any strategies and leaves that up to the user to decide.